# using pointers and vectors

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have to write a code to search for numbers through a vector. I am confused on how to call and use the search function.

bool linearSearch(const vector & v, int x) : 
A linear search algorithm, where x is the searched item in vector v. It simply starts searching for x from the beginning of vector v to the end, but it stops searching when there is a match. If the search is successful, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false. To implement this routine, simply call the find ( 
) function from the STL.

•       bool binarySearch(const vector < int >& v, int x) :
A binary search algorithm, where x is the searched item in vector v. If the search is successful, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false. To implement this routine, simply call the binary_search ( ) function from the STL.

•       int search ( const vector < int >& v1, const vector < int >& v2, bool ( *p ) ( const vector < int >&, int ) 
) : A generic search algorithm – takes a pointer to the search routine p ( ), and then it calls p ( ) for each element of vector v2 in vector v1. It computes the total number of successful searches and returns that value to the main ( ) routine as an input argument to the print routine printStat ( 
), which is used to print out the final statistics for a search algorithm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void genRndNums( vector<int>& v, int vec_size, int seed ) {
    srand(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++)
    {

        int a = (rand() % 1000) + 1;//getting a random number
        v.push_back(a);//adding it to the vector 

    }
}

bool linearSearch(const vector<int>& v, int x) {

    find(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
}

bool binarySearch( const vector<int>& v, int x) {
    if (binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), x))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

int search( const vector<int>& container, const vector<int>& searchNums,
            bool (*p)( const vector<int>&, int) ) {

    int count;
    while ( )
    {
        if ((*p)(const vector<int> & container, int)) == true)
            count= count + 1;

    }

}

void sortVec (vector<int>& v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());//sorting the vector
}

void printStat (int totalSucCnt, int vec_size) {

}

int main() {
    const int TOBE_SEARCHED = 5000;
    vector<int> container, tobeSearched;
    genRndNums(container, 10000, 9);
    genRndNums(tobeSearched, TOBE_SEARCHED, 3);

    cout << "\nConducting linear search ..." << endl;
    int linear_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, linearSearch );
    printStat ( linear_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    cout << "\nConducting binary search on unsorted container ..." << endl;

    int binary_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, binarySearch );
    printStat ( binary_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    sortVec( container );

    cout << "\nConducting binary search on sorted container ..." << endl;
    binary_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, binarySearch );
   // printStat ( binary_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sooo, what's your question? What are you confused of?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask questions more correctly

Comment: @h4ckthepl4net `[ask]` expands to [ask]. Other [fun shortcuts.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @user4581301 oh, ok I didn't know, thank you)

Answer (score 2):

Following is the modified version of your code, which works with both linear search and binary search. The code also illustrates how to pass a function and call the function to search for numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void genRndNums( vector<int>& v, int vec_size, int seed ) {
    srand(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_size; i++)
    {

        int a = (rand() % 1000) + 1;//getting a random number
        v.push_back(a);//adding it to the vector 

    }
}

bool linearSearch(const vector<int>& v, int x) {
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end();
}

/* Works only when the vector is sorted*/
bool binarySearch( const vector<int>& v, int x) {
    return binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), x);
}

int search( const vector<int>& container, const vector<int>& searchNums,
            bool (*p)( const vector<int>&, int) ) {

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<searchNums.size(); i++)
    {
        if (p(container, searchNums[i]) == true)
            count= count + 1;
    }
    return count;

}

void sortVec (vector<int>& v) {
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());//sorting the vector
}

void printStat (int totalSucCnt, int vec_size) {
    cout<<"found " << totalSucCnt << "out of " << vec_size<<endl;
}

void printVec(vector<int> & v){
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

}
int main() {
    const int TOBE_SEARCHED = 50;
    vector<int> container, tobeSearched;
    genRndNums(container, 100, 9);
    genRndNums(tobeSearched, TOBE_SEARCHED, 3);
    //cout<<"vector 1:"<<endl;
    //printVec(container);

    //cout<<"vector 1:"<<endl;
    //printVec(tobeSearched);

    cout << "\nConducting linear search ..." << endl;
    int linear_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, linearSearch );
    printStat ( linear_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    cout << "\nConducting binary search on unsorted container ..." << endl;

    int binary_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, binarySearch );
    printStat ( binary_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    sortVec( container );

    cout << "\nConducting binary search on sorted container ..." << endl;
    binary_search_count = search( container, tobeSearched, binarySearch );
    printStat ( binary_search_count, TOBE_SEARCHED );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not explaining what you have changed and why is not a good way of writing an answer.

Comment: @t.niese thank you for the suggestions, I will update the answer and take care of it for my future answers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still confused on how *p is passed? Also, the output is the same value every time? Thanks so much for your help though.